# More spam than usual?

Tags: discussion

Is it just me or is there more spam than usual the last days? Has anything changed in how we handle spam, making it more visible, or is it just another wave?

Comment: It has always and will always probably come in waves.  Yes, this seems to be one of those waves.

Comment: Yes, I flagged 7 in the last 2 hours, 4 of which only in the last 5 minutes. Never saw a wave so intense before.

Comment: Me neither, hence my question... I'm almost at 30 now...

Comment: There was indeed a spam peak today. One of the CM's was alerted, and changed the spam filter settings for this site, after which the spam subsided.

Comment: Visited the homepage just moments ago and was met with spam sitting in first position. Immediately flagged it. How can one flag an individual user as a spammer or otherwise naughty person?

Comment: I am fairly new to the site but I did notice a huge wave yesterday/last night. However, I also noticed that they were flagged and deleted before I actually got them open. I was suitably impressed. Good job, mods. Is there any way to make them disappear from the screen or is it just a timing issue between my refreshing the page and them being deleted?

Comment: Probably needs to be a separate question/feature request @mheadroom

Comment: @KGIII the front page is slightly cached, so the titles sometimes stick around for ~5 minutes or so, but not long.

Comment: @mheadroom There is no direct way to flag users. You do have several options though. Use a custom flag on one of their posts, those don't get cleared by post deletion. The other is drop by [chat] and ping a moderator. Custom flags work better, but there are some edge cases where they aren't possible.

Comment: @Seth thanks. I'm learning my way around, slowly but surely.

Comment: Don't worry, we have Smoke Detectors placed strategically throughout the network, so it helps remove spam fast.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's ironic that you're asking this question in the middle of a new spam wave...  **>:-)**

When looking at all this going on in the chat room, your meta question looked (*just for a µ-second*) like spam too:

[image]

To answer your questions:

- **Yes**, they come in waves (When some "SEO optimizing company" gets hired, probably)
- **No**, we still handle it the usual way (humans flagging it as spam)
- **No**, we're not making it more visible. (You've just seem your first spam wave apparently)
- We even have a standard saying: [SPAM WAVE!  Man the SPAM stations!](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24615502#24615502)

### ;-)

<sub>Now I'm going back to flag some spam again</sub>

Comment: One of the benefits of Ask Ubuntu being a larger member of the Stack Exchange network is that there are always enough eyeballs on the home page to make sure spam disappears within seconds of being posted.